# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, typeerror

```
@client.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx):

  with open("balance.json", "r") as bal:
    
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_balance_data()#line-45
    balance = users[str(user.id)]["balance"] = 0
    
    embedbalance = discord.Embed(titles=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color=discord.Color.blue())
    embedbalance.add_field(name="balance", value=balance)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedbalance)
  
  
async def get_balance_data():
  with open("balance.json", "w") as balance: #line-54
    users = json.loads(balance.read())
    json.dump(users, balance)

  return users

client.run(token)
```

The error I'm getting is:
File "(the bot's path)", line 54, in get_balance_data
with open("balance.json", "r", "w") as balance:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```open()``` requires filename and mode.  If you want read-only, use ```"r"```.  If you want read/write, use ```"w"```.

Comment: On doing "w" I'm getting the following error:
UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Answer (score 1):

The [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in function in Python has the following signature:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

The third parameter (`buffer`) is used to set the buffering policy and it expects an (optional) integer. So, by passing the string `"w"` instead of an integer, you run up against the `TypeError` you described. Perhaps you meant to open the file in read-write mode instead (i.e., `with open("balance.json", "r+") as balance`)?

As a side-note, it seems odd that your `async def balance` functions opens the same file, but does nothing with it. It also seems odd that lines 54-56 read the contents of the file and then write the same contents back out to the file (though perhaps there's some redacted context that I'm missing).